# how to display a relationship is swagger, typeorm and nestjs

Tags: swagger, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-typeorm

using `@nestjs/swagger` and `@nestjs/typeorm`, how to properly display a relationship field in swagger UI.

for example:

```
@Entity()
class MyEntity{
  @ManyToOne(() => StoreEntity, (store) => store.checkouts)
  @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', format: 'uuid', name: 'storeId' })
  store: StoreEntity;

}
```

I want that field to be displayed in swagger as a string to enter only the store's id, but in typeORM to be s `storeEntity` object.
so, `req.body.store` can be just a string, but `response.store` is the full object

without separating them like that ...

```
  @ManyToOne(() => StoreEntity, (store) => store.checkouts)
  @ApiHideProperty()
  store: StoreEntity;

  @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', format: 'uuid' })
  storeId: string;
```